# xslt apply templates under a group using count function

Tags: xml, xslt

The number of "can" elements in the output should be equal to the number of occurences of the "c" element under "a" element in the input xml. So first consecutive occurences of "can" element should be 3(as the first consecutive occurences of c elemet under a in the input is 3) and the next consecutive occurence of "can" elements should be 2, as per the input. However in my current output it gets repeated in total(5).I think the below line should be changed, but not sure how, tried using position() as well. That is apply templates only to c under first(using count ../) a, then second a.

The line, I believe that should be changed

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*[$coun]/c"/>
```

My input xml

```
<Root>
  <a>
    <b>12</b>
    <c>1</c>
    <c>2</c>
    <c>3</c>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>12</b>
    <c>a</c>
    <c>c</c>
  </a>
</Root>
```

My xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/b"/>
      </Root>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="b">
    <a>
      <xsl:value-of select="../b"/>
    </a>
    <xsl:variable name="coun">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::a) + 1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*[$coun]/c"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="c">
    <can>abc</can>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my current output

```
<Root>
  <a>12</a>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <a>12</a>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
</Root>
```

my expected output

```
<Root>
  <a>12</a>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
  <a>12</a>
  <can>abc</can>
  <can>abc</can>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input:

```
<Root>
  <a>
    <b>12</b>
    <c>1</c>
    <c>2</c>
    <c>3</c>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b>12</b>
    <c>a</c>
    <c>c</c>
  </a>
</Root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match='b'>
    <a>
        <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='c'>
    <can>abc</can>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='/Root'>
    <Root>
        <!-- select all 'b' and 'c' elements within an 'a' element -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select='a/b | a/c'/>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<Root>
    <a>12</a>
    <can>abc</can>
    <can>abc</can>
    <can>abc</can>
    <a>12</a>
    <can>abc</can>
    <can>abc</can>
</Root>
```